# RGBDSLAM Cannot produce Octomap

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got RGBDSLAM working on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I am using ROS Fuerte and Xbox Kinect. I can save the map as .pcl and .ply, but I can't get any octomap. When I press "send model" in RGBDSLAM and save a map using octomap_saver and try to view it using octovis it only shows an empty cube (which means no map).

I used rostopic echo /rgbdslam/batch_clouds while running RGBDSLAM but nothing is being published on that topic! I checked the settings in RGBDSLAM and individual_cloud_out_topic and it is set to the right topic (which is /rgbdslam/batch_clouds).

What could be preventing the data from being published on that topic? Any thoughts on how I can generate an octomap?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53228/rgbdslam-cannot-produce-octomap/) by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you disabled "store_pointclouds" in your launch-file? It is on by default.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on 2013-01-28**:
I removed a few lines in the launch file including that and it worked. Thanks.

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-05-07**:
Hi Medrad can I see your launch file? I also cannot see any output when I use typed the command  rostopic echo /rgbdslam/batch_clouds. There is also no topic published from the rgbdslam node in the rxgraph. By the way is it the kinect+rgbdslam.launch file?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-13**:
batch_clouds is only published on command, i.e. from the GUI menu or ros service call. If you want to use/visualize the aligned clouds as they are processed, subscribe to the pointcloud from openni_launch and transform them to the tf frame /map that is published by rgbdslam.

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-05-14**:
I see! after pressing Ctrl+M or clicking on "send model" under "Data", values starts to show up under rostopic echo /rgbdslam/batch_clouds. Thanks Felix! Where should I look at if I want to automate this proces based on a variable that I will publish from my own program that will run simultaneously?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-16**:
In your own program call the ros service  "/rgbdslam/ros_ui" with command "send_all". See the ros wiki tutorials for how to call services.